# Accessing app on the server disallows image loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have an issue while deploying my ASP.NET MVC project. If I'm accessing it locally, everything works fine, but as I access it from my home pc to the server where it's hosted I get an error 403 Forbidden for each image.

Any thoughts?

This is how it should look like :

[How It Should Look like http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/809/3vc8.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/809/3vc8.png)

This is how it looks (these are my default images that get loaded if the correct image can't be loaded) :

[How It Looks Like http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/542/09sr.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/542/09sr.png)

These are the errors via Chrome Console :

[Errors http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/yuqg.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/yuqg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late response, but better late than never. The issue at hand was that I was hot-linking (http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking) the images from Imdb. At the time I didn't know that I was doing that. When I put all of the images on my server, in the appropriate folders, everything worked fine.

Guess I answered my own question.